# How to enable scheduled updates

Tags: apt, updates, automation

I know that you can make it so that security updates are downloaded and installed automatically, but you seem to be unable to do this with other updates, also, I don't want them just to be installed at any time, I want to be able to set it up so that the machine automatically updates everything that needs updating at a set time each day. So I was wondering how this could be achieved, because I haven't seen any options which seem to enable anything like this?

**Contextual Information:**

This is not for my machine, but instead another machine which I am managing and cannot be on the whole time to update, but needs to be regularly updated without user intervention.

Comment: I run Terminal in my startup programs.  My zsh .zshrc  file runs a script that executes apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, apt-get dist-upgrade, apt-get autoclean.  My system updater is rarely ever activated. To run unattended at boot-up and without password, you'll have to edit the sudoers file.

Comment: @RCF-U15.04: What about the "[Y/n]" prompt? How is that dealt with in a script without user intervention?

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade

Comment: @RCF-U15.04: Could you please convert all that into an answer explaining how to add it to my startup programs and what the script contains that is executed etc... So that I can accept it.

Comment: I found my answer over here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213053/set-a-scheduled-time-for-software-updates and it seems to work for me.

Comment: Since you have excluded security upgrades, the only other upgrade you "need" would be bugfixes for any bugs that you suffer from. You are unlikely to notice generic non-security upgrades. So simply mark your calendar once a month.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a scheduled time for software updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213053/set-a-scheduled-time-for-software-updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your favorite editor and create a script file similar to this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh  ### I use zsh, enter your shell here.
sudo apt-get -qq update
sudo apt-get -y -qq upgrade
exit                  ### Be sure to include this exit line
```

Make your **Your_Script_File.sh** executable.

```
chmod +x <your_script_file.sh>
```

Next, edit the **sudoers** file.

Open a **terminal** and enter

```
    sudo visudo
```

At the end of the file (really, the last line) add the following lines.

```
<user_name>  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/<user_name>/script_name.sh
<user_name>  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get -qq update
<user_name>  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get -y -qq upgrade
```

After that you won't be prompted for a password for the commands listed.  These lines should include the exact commands used in your script.  You will no longer be prompted for a password, and the **-qq** eliminates the scrolling output in the terminal window.  Please understand this is a very risky solution, there is a reason why you need to type a password for some commands, the use of these commands without password can leave your system open for some dangers. Use with caution.  I like the `-qq` option because it is rarely used by most users and if they run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The system will require a password.

Next, <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> open **Startup Applications**.

This will run the **Startup Applications Preferences** dialog window.
Click **Add**.  Give it a name, I used "startUpdate".  In the **Command** box enter the command

```
    xterm -e ./<your_script_name
```

Xterm recognizes the **exit** from the script and will close the window, when execution is complete.

The user will see a blank **xterm** window for a couple of minutes, then it closes.

Hope this works for you.